# listview doesn't scroll after filtering

Tags: android, listview, filter, adapter

I have a listview. And I have also a custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter. In my custom adapter I implemented interface Filterable. After filtering I call notifyDataSetChanged() method of adapter, then it works fine ( It updates the list items ). But, after this I can't scroll my listview.
Why this happens?

**ANSWER:** This happens because my listview was inside the GridLayout, when I changed GridLayout to LinearLayout and set some proper parameters it worked perfectly.

Comment: After filtering do you have a more items to be scroll

Comment: yes, I have more items to be scrolled.

Comment: Go ahead and answer your own question below.